# use react to change css when selectors are typed out

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a page similar to this: [Samuel Reed](http://strml.net/),
where the css is changing when the selectors are typed out.
I've created `onClick` functions that works as I want them to but I'm not sure how to make them work without the links. If someone could point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated!

This is my code, I'm using ReactJS

```
var ColorChanger = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      color: '#f00',
      backgroundColor: '#fff'
    };
  },
  changeColor: function() {
    this.setState({
      color: '#00f'
    });
  },
  changeBGColor: function() {
    this.setState({
      backgroundColor: '#000'
    });
  },
  changePadding: function() {
    this.setState({
      padding: '10px'
    });
  },
  changeWidth: function() {
    this.setState({
      width: '400px'
    });
  },
  changeMargin: function() {
    this.setState({
      margin: '0 auto'
    });
  },
  render: function(){
    var style = {
      color: this.state.color,
      backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor,
      padding: this.state.padding,
      width: this.state.width,
      margin: this.state.margin
    };
      return (
          <div style={style}>
              <a onClick={this.changeColor}>color: #00f;</a> <br />
              <a onClick={this.changeBGColor}>backgroundcolor: #000;</a> <br />
              <a onClick={this.changePadding}>padding: 10px;</a> <br />
              <a onClick={this.changeWidth}>width: 400px;</a> <br />
              <a onClick={this.changeMargin}>margin: 0 auto;</a>
          </div>
      );
  }

});

React.render(<ColorChanger />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

I've also created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y6Lduwd2/3/) with the code

Answer (score 0):

You should create an Input component that will be changing the state as soon as you change the Input. Since ReactJS is so modular you can use this Input with your code as a mixin on everything you do. And then change the CSS for that Input to be seen as a normal label/text.

Also you can do this with TextArea or, better, with `pre` HTML Element.

```
var Input = React.createClass({

    mixins: [ColorStatesMixin], // Import your code here as a mixin.

    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            value: ''
        };
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <input {...this.getProps()} />
        );
    },

    getProps: function () {
        // Return all the props here.
        return {
            onChange: this.setNewValue
        };
    },

    setNewValue: function (event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }
});
```

This should do a similar work. Need some good touches but it works. Similar with `pre` that it's actually better than Input. With this one you can change every input color.

**EDIT:** Actually the input it's not the best selection. You should do something like `TextArea` or `pre` and then parse the value following this concept. When I check his code I saw that he's using others code to the typing effect.

You can also use `classnames` module to add classes dynamically to your code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but maybe I was a bit unclear. I don't want an input, I want the text to be printed directly on page load. Any suggestion how I can achieve that?